# Scopes required for executing "gcloud container clusters create" on GCE VM instance

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to create a GKE cluster by executing the following command on a GCE VM instance:

```
sudo gcloud container clusters create my-cluster \
  --machine-type g1-small --num-nodes 1
```

Execution fails with this error message (despite `kubectl` being installed):

```
WARNING: Accessing a Container Engine cluster requires the kubernetes commandline client [kubectl].
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=403, message=Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

This problem is perhaps cause by the VM instance not possessing enough scopes. It currently possesses the following ones. Which other scope(s) is required in order for the problem to disappear?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Container Engine requires the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` scope, so you'll need to select "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs" when you create the VM instance.

Comment: Yep that worked for me; I just stopped the instance which then allowed me to edit the scopes before starting the VM up again